# How to pass the JSON data into the PostgresSql Database using python

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.5

I have a JSON file. I tried to pass the JSON data into the PSQL

## I tried this So far

```
import psycopg2
import json
with open('jsondata.json') as f:
        data = f.read()
        dd= json.loads(data)

print(dd)
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testdb", user = "postgres",  password = "postgres",host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")

print "Opened database successfully"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE test(SUM INT NOT NULL,
                                      APP  CHAR[30] NOT NULL,
                                                      ID INT NOT NULL,
                                                      DOMAINNAME TEXT NOT NULL,
                                      DOMAINID INT NOT NULL);''')
print "Table Created successfully"

print(type(data))
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(SUM,APP,ID,DOMAINNAME,DOMAINID) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)", (str(dd["sum"]),str(dd["app"]),str(dd["id"]),str(dd["Domain_name"]),str(dd["Domain_Id"])))
print "Data Entered successfully"
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print "connection closed successfully"
```

## I am getting this error

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(SUM,APP,ID,DOMAINNAME,DOMAINID) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5::json)", (str(dd["sum"]),str(dd["app"]),str(dd["id"]),str(dd["Domain_name"]),str(dd["Domain_Id"])))
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

## I am expecting output

[Expecting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XT4u.png)

Comment: please, provide a sample of JSON

Comment: from error it seems that your `dd` is a `list` (possibly `list` of `dict`s), but you are treating it like a `dict`

Comment: My sample json----------> [{
 "sum": 2102.0,
 "app": "java",
 "appId": "1234",
 "Domain_name": "medicine",
 "Domain_Id": "20000123"
}, {
 "sum": 1800.0,
 "app": "python",
 "appId": "37345",
 "Domain_name": "engineering",
 "Domain_Id": "823445"
}]